# Casperjs: How to manipulate javascript paging( links overloaded by javascript)

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, casperjs, paging

Using casperjs, I'm working on scraping some informaion from a web site, in this page there is a paging created by overloading a link

```
<a id="ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2"     
href="javascript:;//ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2"><img 
src="themes/images/fleche-suivant.gif" alt="Aller à la page suivante"></a>
```

there are two methods to access to the next page:

1. to click on the next button
   [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Soj.png)
2. or to change the value of the field [as shown in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9tDO.png) and click the enter key on the keyboard

I've tried both methods but didn't work, could someone please help me to code one of them.

```
var mouse = require("mouse").create(casper);
var url = '';
var url2 = '';
var tst;
casper.test.begin('Scraping start', function(test) {
casper.start(url, function() {
    this.test.pass('Opened 1st page');
})
.thenOpen(url2, function(){
    this.test.pass('Opened 2nd page')
})
.then(function(){

 //these are the tow methodes I try to click on the next button
//this.mouse.click("#ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2");   
this.thenClick(' div.liens a#ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2');
})

.then(function() {
    tst = this.evaluate(function() {
    return 
__utils__.getFieldValue( 
'[name="ctl0$CONTENU_PAGE$resultSearch$numPageTop"]');   
});
})
.run(function() {
    console.log(tst);
    test.done();
});
});
```

the version of casperjs is 1.1.4 and I'm using the phantom browser

Comment: Provide your console log with `log-level=true` flag

Comment: Actually both of these flags `--verbose --log-level=debug`

Comment: thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally navigates to 2nd page on my end. Try it, also you can save screenshot for more debugging purposes.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = 'https://www.marchespublics.gov.ma/index.php5?page=entreprise.EntrepriseAdvancedSearch&AllCons&EnCours&domaineActivite=1.15';

casper
    .start(url, function() {
        this.echo('Opened page ' + this.evaluate(function() {
            return document.title;
        }), 'INFO');
    })
    .then(function() {
        if (this.exists('a[id="ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2"]')) {
            this.echo('the heading exists');
        } else {
            this.echo('Does not exist');
        }
    })
    .thenClick('div.liens a#ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_resultSearch_PagerTop_ctl2')
    .wait(5000)
    .then(function() {
        this.capture('exit.png');
    })
    .run();
```

Hope that helps!